# AS3 Call function from Another function

Tags: actionscript-3, function

I have a function called processXML on the timeline (yes, I know now...) which does what I want it to do e.g. it loads XML, is passed into several arrays and manipulates things on screen. Cool

I have another function, a TIMER, from which I'd like to call the function above e.g. processXML.call()

(I want it to load fresh data every 10-20 seconds)

But no luck. I'm new to AS3 but can't seem to get it working.

Am I missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just `processXML()` should work. This, obviously, if both functions are at the same level on the timeline.

Or simply when your first frame is loaded you can do

```
var xmlInterval:Number=-1;
var msGap:Number=20000; //Sets the millisecond gap to 20000 milliseconds between calls
xmlInterval=setInterval(processXML, msGap); //calls processXML every msGap milliseconds
//And to stop calling processXML when you don't need it,
clearInterval(xmlInterval);
```

Comment: @user1203605, can you post your processXML code here? Or at least just the first (function signature) line?

Comment: var myXML:XML;
 var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
 myLoader.load(new URLRequest("myText.xml")); 
 myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
 
 function processXML(e:Event):void {
  myXML = new XML(e.target.data);

Comment: It sees processXML is being called by the load event of an xml loader. So instead of doing `setInterval(processXML, msGap);` you need to use `setInterval(loadXML, msGap);` where loadXML will call `loader.load(URLRequest)`;

Comment: Yep, discovered that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this?:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var aTimer:Timer = new Timer(10000); // 10 seconds
aTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timeToDoSomethingAgain);

function timeToDoSomethingAgain(evt:TimerEvent):void {
    trace("timeToDoSomethingAgain");
    processXML(); //Call your function, DO NOT SAY processXML.call() as this is incorrect
}

function processXML():void {
    //Stuff in your function
}
```

Also, are you wanting to load the xml from file every 10-20 seconds or just reference an already loaded xml object?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do something like the above. But Flash doesn't like me calling processXML(); Everything else works similar to the example you gave.

Comment: Waiting to self answer - being a nube 'n all. Anyway... Ok, my bad. Couldn't see the wood for the trees.

Easy answer, really.

Just needed to put  myLoader.load(new URLRequest("myText.xml"));

in the timer function. processXML fires any time it loads... Doh!